# How to write the content of a void pointer?

Tags: c++, memory, binary, void, gmp

How is it possible to `cout` bit-by-bit the bits stored at a `void` pointer in cpp?

```
void * r = malloc(k*8);
size_t count;
//Print string under byte form with bytes separated by space
cout << mpz_export (r, &count, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t());
```

This `cout` writes only the address.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bits stored at a void pointer"?

Comment: There is no content at void pointer. That's the point of the void pointer: it points to no content, just location. If you need a byte (an unsigned char), you need an unsigned char pointer. If you need an int, you need an int pointer. Cast your pointer to the correct type.

Comment: mpz_export (r, &count, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t()); exports to void r  the number stored in cypher. I want to check & write what bytes have been exported to r. Here the dicumentation: https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html

Comment: When using void pointers you deny the compiler the knowledge of the type the pointers is pointing to and hence basically imply that you know better. Let's skip the discussion whether that is wise. But it means that you should know which type it is pointing to, possibly in each of the several different possibilities. So you know a type you can cast to and then output it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
char* ptr = (char*)mpz_export(r, &count, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t());
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << (unsigned)(unsigned char)ptr[i] << ' ';
cout << '\n';
```

Since you data is `char` data, you must cast the `void` pointer to a `char` pointer. Then to see the output as unsigned integers (which I presume is what you want) then you have to cast each `char` to an `unsigned char` and then an `unsigned`.

If you want hex output then just add the usual formatting code.

Comment: You should cast the return value of `mpz_export()` to `unsigned char *` instead of to `char *`. Also, assuming the output data is binary, consider using `std::hex` to make the output bytes more human readable

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
Function: size_t mpz_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, const mpz_t op)
```

Output op on stdio stream stream, as a string of digits in base base. The base argument may vary from 2 to 62 or from -2 to -36.For base in the range 2..36, digits and lower-case letters are used; for -2..-36, digits and upper-case letters are used; for 37..62, digits, upper-case letters, and lower-case letters (in that significance order) are used. Return the number of bytes written, or if an error occurred, return 0

More information can be found here :https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the OP wants to see the actual bytes representing the integer, that's why they call `mpz_export`, rather than see the integer converted to some base.